# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I'm new with Hadoop and the ecosystem. I'm trying Hive with JDBC in Java.
This is my simple code only to test the driver:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class PrepareHiveTable {
    private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName(driverName);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default", "", "");
    }
}
```

I've imported `org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver` to the classpath and this is the driver list on my `DriverManager`:

```
org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Driver@45ff54e6
org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver@3581c5f3
org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver40@4f8e5cde
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@6f75e721
org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver@69222c14
```

But when I run the code I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at PrepareHiveTable.main(PrepareHiveTable.java:24)
Java Result: 1
```

Anyone here know how can it happen? And how to solve it?

Comment: I found the solution. I use hive 1.2.1 so I need to write jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default instead of jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default

thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the solution. I use hive 1.2.1 so I need to write `jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default` instead of `jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default`

thank you

Comment: I'm using hive-jdbc-2.3.2.jar. How should I do to get the connection?

Comment: @mannedear does `jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default` work for u?

Comment: No Wil, I changed my hive-jdbc version to 1.0.0 and it worked out. I have shared the jars I used to get the connection in the answer section which may help few more people struggling with versions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `hive-jdbc-1.0.0.jar` and I got the connection established successfully to hive db. I'm also sharing other details which I used here.

Driver Name: `org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver`
URL: `("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default","username","password")`

Below are the total jars I used for my project to work on hive db from my java project.

[image]