# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default while connecting using jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, hive

I am trying to execute my java code using jsp. The code contains hive connection and few simple queries. When I just run the java code it is executing properly, but when executing using jsp it shows the error in the title.

java code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.*;
import org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver;
public class Hive {
public void hive1() throws SQLException {

try{

String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "hduser", "abc");

System.out.println("Connected");
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
+" tweets5 ( id BIGINT, created_at STRING, "
+"source STRING, "
+"favorited BOOLEAN, "
+" retweet_count INT,"
+"retweeted_status STRUCT< "
+"text:STRING, "
+" user:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>,"
+"retweet_count:INT>, "
+" entities STRUCT< "
+"urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>, "
+"user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>, "
+" hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,"
+" text STRING,"
+" user STRUCT<"
+"screen_name:STRING, "
+"name:STRING, "
+"locations:STRING, "
+"friends_count:INT, " 
+" followers_count:INT,"
+"statuses_count:INT, "
+"verified:BOOLEAN, "
+"utc_offset:INT, "
+"time_zone:STRING>, "
+ " in_reply_to_screen_name STRING)"
+" ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'"
+" LOCATION '/user/flume/tweets'");
System.out.println("Table created successfully");


String sql = "describe tweets5";
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while (res.next()) 
{      
    System.out.println(res.getString(1) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
}



sql = "select id,user.name from tweets5";
System.out.println("\nRunning: " + sql);
res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while (res.next()) {
System.out.println(String.valueOf(res.getString(1)) + "\t" +     String.valueOf(res.getString(2)));
}
}
System.out.println("Operation done successfully.");
stmt.close();
conn.close();

System.out.println("End");
}catch(SQLException se){
se.printStackTrace();
}

catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
/*
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

Hive h = new Hive();
h.hive1();
}
*/
}
```

jsp code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ page import="hive.Hive" %>

<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>

<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>page4</title>
</head>
<body>


   <% 

   Hive h = new Hive();
   h.hive1();

   %>

   <%= "<h1> Processing started....</h1>" %>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try using Google to search for the error message? This is one of the most common errors and the question has been answered hundreds of times.

Comment: Maybe you haven't deployed the corresponding jar in your WEB-INF\lib directory on the server that you're executing your JSP.

Comment: check your path contains the driver lib

Comment: I already tried that, but its showing same error @RubioRic

Comment: @JimGarrison I am not getting the error while running normal java code which is a common problem, but running using a jsp is showing errors

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722139/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbchive-localhost10000 May be is this the problem??

Comment: @Ajinkya if it works standalone and not in the Servlet container, then you have not included the required jar file(s) in your deployment so they can be seen by the servlet engine.

Comment: You can try Class.forName(jdbcDriver); before obtaining the connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616898/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmicrosoftsqlserver)

Answer (score 1):

You declare "driverName", but never use it.

Try adding:

```
try {
      Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
```

(From https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/25410/simple-steps-to-test-hive-jdbc-connect.html)